# Question concerning finite rings

Tags: ring-theory, finite-rings

Let $R$ be a finite ring. Is it possible that $R$ has an element $a\in R$ such that $a$ is a left divisor of zero and  $a$ is not right divisor of zero?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Richard: I guess you've tried something so far... can you describe what happened, briefly? It doesn't matter if it was a success or you got stuck. Adding these sorts of details will make your question more attractive to answer.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand details. If there exist $b \neq 0$ s.t. $ba=0$ then $r\mapsto ra$ is not 1-1 and consequently not surjective. But why there is $c\neq 0$ s.t. $ac=0$?

Comment: Good start, Richard. For my hint, be sure to start by assuming $a$ isn't a right zero divisor. What can you tell me about the map?

Comment: (And do you want your ring to have identity?)

Comment: Dear Richard (and others), Regarding the existence of an identity, the argument [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/45220/221) could be relevant.  Regards,

Comment: @rschwieb: Dear rschwieb, The argument linked in my previous comment could fit well with your suggested method to deal with the identity issue.  Regards,

Comment: If $a$ is not right divisor of zero then this map is bijection and if $R$ has units then there is $c$ such that $ca=1$. Hence if $a$ would be the left divisor, then for some $b \neq 0$ $ab=0$.Hence  $b=(ca)b=c(ab)=0$ -a contradiction.

Comment: @Richard Great! :)

Comment: @MattE Ahh of course, some power of $a$ must be the identity map :) Good call!

Comment: @rschwieb: Dear rschwieb, Actually, I guess this doesn't work, as Boris Novikov's answer below shows.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE Hm, I thought I was convinced by your argument right away, and there are things to check in Boris's example...

Comment: @rschwieb: Dear rschwieb, Without $1$ in the ring, the map from $R$ to $End(R)$ by taking right multiplication (say) need not be injective (it won't be in Boris's example), and so just because something acts by right multiplication as the identity, doesn't make it an identity in the ring (and so it needn't act identically by left multiplication).  I guess this means that commutativity is really needed in my argument from the other question.  Regards,

Comment: Yeah, you're right that since there are many things acting as right identity and none as the left identity, and that's where the argument breaks down :S Interesting. It's a rather dramatic example :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S$ be a finite semigroup of left zeroes ($ab=a$ for all $a,b\in S$), $F$ a finite field, $FS$ the semigroup ring of $S$ over $F$. Then $a(b-c)=0$, so every $a$ is a left divisor of zero but not a right divisor.

(Thanks @rschwieb for a remark)

Comment: Interesting and a little scary :)

Comment: @rschwieb: Excuse me my ignorance in English: what does "scary" mean?

Comment: I just meant to express how different finite rngs can be from finite rings :)

Comment: @rschwieb: 1) Thank you. I asked because Google translates  "scary" into Russian as a synonym of "terrible" :-)

Comment: Oh! No, not terrible :)

Comment: @rschwieb: OP didn't demand of existence of 1. Thank you for remark, I will correct the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hints (which come under the assumption that the ring has identity):

On a finite set $X$, a mapping from $X$ to $X$ is 1-1 iff it is onto.

Suppose $a$ is not a right divisor of zero.

The mapping $r\mapsto ra$ is a homomorphism of left $R$ modules from $R$ to $R$. By an elementary proposition, all left module homomorphisms from $R$ to $R$ have this form.

What do the hypotheses say about this map? Might it have an inverse?